# Typescript inherited interface and literal string type key error

Tags: typescript, typescript2.1

I have 3 interfaces (`A`, `B`, and `C` below) that all extend from a common interface (`Common` below). I also have a container type that contains arrays of these 3 interfaces (`Container` below).

I want to grab one of the arrays and pluck a common property from the objects, as shown in getCommon()`:

```
interface Common {
    common: boolean;
}

interface A extends Common {
    a: A[];
}

interface B extends Common {
    b: B[];
}

interface C extends Common {
    c: C[];
}

type Container = {
    a: A[],
    b: B[],
    c: C[]
};

let item: Container = {
    a: [ { a: [], common: true } ],
    b: [ { b: [], common: true } ],
    c: [ { c: [], common: true } ]
};

type Key = 'a' | 'b' | 'c';

function getCommon (thisKey: Key) {
    return item[thisKey].map(a => a.common); // This line has an error
}
```

[Typescript Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20Common%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20common%3A%20boolean%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20A%20extends%20Common%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20A%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20B%20extends%20Common%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20B%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20C%20extends%20Common%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%20C%5B%5D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Key%20%3D%20'a'%20%7C%20'b'%20%7C%20'c'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Container%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20A%5B%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20B%5B%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%20C%5B%5D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20item%3A%20Container%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20%5B%20%7B%20a%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%20common%3A%20true%20%7D%20%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20%5B%20%7B%20b%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%20common%3A%20true%20%7D%20%5D%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%20%5B%20%7B%20c%3A%20%5B%5D%2C%20common%3A%20true%20%7D%20%5D%0D%0A%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20getCommon%20(thisKey%3A%20Key)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20item%5BthisKey%5D.map(a%20%3D%3E%20a.common)%3B%0D%0A%7D)

However, Typescript 2.1 is giving me a compile error:

```
Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature. 
Type '{ <U>(this: [A, A, A, A, A], callbackfn: (value: A, index: number, array: A[]) => U, 
thisArg?: an...' has no compatible call signatures.
```

Is this a bug/limitation in Typescript, or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It seems it is a limitation. But you can help the compiler by given it the type of the array: `(A | B | C)[]`.

```
function getCommon(thisKey: Key) {
    let arr: (A | B | C)[] = item[thisKey];
    return arr.map(a => a.common);
}
```

Comment: So it seems that the root issue is that the TS compiler doesn't thing `A[] | B[]` has a `map` property but thinks `(A | B)[]` does? That's a bummer (and seems like a bug) since the former type actually represents what's happening more than the latter.

Comment: Just created https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13097 since this seems like undesired behavior. We'll see what the community/core team says about it!